# How to find the number of rows that has been updated in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can we find the number of rows that got updated in pandas.

```
New['Updated']= np.where((New.Class=='B')&(New.Flag=='Y'),'N',np.where((New.Class=='R')&(New.Flag=='N'),'Y',New.Flag))
data.Flag=data['Tracking_Nbr'].map(New.set_index('Tracking_Nbr').Updated)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need store the Flag before the change , here I using Flag1

```
df2['Updated']=np.where((df2.Class=='B')&(df2.Flag=='Y'),'N',np.where((df2.Class=='R')&(df2.Flag=='N'),'Y',df2.Flag))

df1['Flag1']=df1['Flag']
df1.Flag=df1['Tracking_Nbr'].map(df2.set_index('Tracking_Nbr').Updated)

df1[df1['Flag1']!=df1['Flag']]
```

More information

```
df1['Flag1']!=df1['Flag']
Out[716]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
dtype: bool
```